# Load Multiple types of Documents at Once

Tags: ravendb, nosql

I have two separate document types

```
public class One
{
  public int Id { get;set;  }
  public string Name { get;set; }
}
public class Two
{
  public int Id { get;set; }
  public string Name { get;set; }
}
```

I have a second object that holds a reference to these two documents

```
public class FeedMeDocs
{
   public One one {get;set;}
   public Two two {get;set;
}
```

Is it possible in **one** call to the database to fill the FeedMeDocs object given the document Id's.

Something like this

```
var numbers = session.Load<One>("1").AlsoLoad<Two>("2")
              .ProjectInto<FeedMeDocs>();
```

This is horribly psuedo coded but just a general idea of what I'm after. I looked into the `includes` method but this doesn't seem to be a valid use case because these two documents are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lazy loading](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/how-to/perform-operations-lazily):

```
Lazy<One> oneLazy = session.Advanced.Lazily.Load<One>("ones/1");
Lazy<Two> twoLazy = session.Advanced.Lazily.Load<Two("twos/2");

var numbers = new FeedMeDocs() {
    one = oneLazy.Result,
    two = twoLazy.Result
};
```

On the first access of one of the `Lazy<>`'s `Result` the session will query the server for the collected `Load`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Are `One` and `Two` truly [aggregate roots](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/theory/document-structure-design) that need to be stored directly (eg: why not just store `FeedMeDocs` in ravendb)? You can't come into a documentdb with a relational database mindset, or you'll end up solving the wrong problems.

That said, it's fairly simple to do what you're attempting, given you are loading single documents by id for each:

```
var numbers = new FeedMeDocs() {
    one = session.Load<One>("1"),
    two = session.Load<Two>("2")
};
```

Comment: Yes One and Two are aggregrate roots and will need to be persisted. FeedMeDocs (along with other properties) will be persisted as well. This will call the server twice correct? I was hoping it could be done in one shot, I just stumbled upon [multi map](http://ayende.com/blog/89089/ravendb-multi-maps-reduce-indexes) maybe I could leverage that.